# Selecting a location to save a richTextBox text in a windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically I am trying to make it so when I click on the save button it allows me to choose where I want to save the text file, rather than the text file be saved in an automatic location using the code below:

```
{
            File.WriteAllText("The Hudson", richTextBox1.Text);
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(@"D:\My Documents\text.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

}
```

Comment: Use something similar to a [file open picker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847)

Answer (score 1):

System.Windows.Forms provides a [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) Class specifically for this purpose.

```
{
     if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
     {
        File.WriteAllText("The Hudson", richTextBox1.Text);
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
     }
}
```

Extra bonus: The save file dialog also has a built in file overwrite protection - so if you select a file that already exists, it will show a message box asking the user whether to overwrite the file or not.